# How to concatenate values of a laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel, collections

Here is a small challenge for Laravel fanboys :-)

I want to build a simple list of request segments along to their url.

I start with:

```
// http://domain/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd
$breadcrumbs = collect(explode('/', $request->path()))
```

But I don't know how to **map** it to a collection looking like:

```
$breadcrumbs = collect([
    ['title' => 'aaa', 'link' => 'http://domain/aaa'],
    ['title' => 'bbb', 'link' => 'http://domain/aaa/bbb'],
    ['title' => 'ccc', 'link' => 'http://domain/aaa/bbb/ccc'],
    ['title' => 'ddd', 'link' => 'http://domain/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd'],
])
```

I could easily do it with a `for` loop but I am looking for a really elegant way to do it. I tried with `map()` or `each()` without success.

As Adam Wathan says: "Never write another loop again." ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few ways you can go about doing this, but since you will inevitably require knowledge of past items, I would suggest using `reduce()`. Here's a basic example that will show you how to build up the strings. You could easily add links, make the carry into an array, etc.

```
collect(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'])
    ->reduce(function ($carry, $item) {
        return $carry->push($carry->last() . '/' . $item);
    }, collect([]));
```

Results in

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#928
    #items: array:4 [
        0 => "/aaa"
        1 => "/aaa/bbb"
        2 => "/aaa/bbb/ccc"
        3 => "/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd"
    ]
}
```

Not claiming it's by any means optimised, but it does work. :)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for... I overlooked the docs and missed the `reduce()` method.

Comment: Glad you liked it. :)

Comment: Cool. I was also looking for a function like this. It works even in L5.2

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but a bit different approach - works in Laravel 5.1 and up.

```
//your collection
$breadcrumbs = collect([
    ['title' => 'aaa', 'link' => 'http://domain/aaa'],
    ['title' => 'bbb', 'link' => 'http://domain/aaa/bbb'],
    ['title' => 'ccc', 'link' => 'http://domain/aaa/bbb/ccc'],
    ['title' => 'ddd', 'link' => 'http://domain/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd'],
])

//one-liner to get you what you want
$result = explode(',', $breadcrumbs->implode('link', ','));

//here is what you will get:
array:4 [▼
  0 => "http://domain/aaa"
  1 => "http://domain/aaa/bbb"
  2 => "http://domain/aaa/bbb/ccc"
  3 => "http://domain/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd"
]
```